this.$slots.default.filter is not a function в проекте vue с библиотекой vue glide
У меня в проекте появляется ошибка связанная с библиотекой vue glide, при этом ошибка указывает на фильтрацию хотя я не использую фильтрацию, а использую слайдер-карусель. Ниже опишу свой код:
<template>
    <div class="slider-template">
        <glide>
            <glide-slide>Slide 1</glide-slide>
            <glide-slide>Slide 2</glide-slide>
            <glide-slide>Slide 3</glide-slide>
        </glide>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Glide, GlideSlide } from 'vue-glide-js'

export default {
    name: 'slider-template',
    components: {
        Glide,
        GlideSlide
    }
}
</script>

Читал документацию, искал в интернете. Ожидал что это поможет мне решить проблему и убрать ошибку, но получилось так что все подсказки в интернете объясняют как решить проблему с фильтрацией, а мне нужно ее убрать.
